# "Skeleton project" or "Blank project"

Tags: expressions, expression-choice, programming

What is the correct wording for a (programming context: PHP, Javascript, HTML, ...) project folder (= a set of files / scripts) someone else can use as a starting point?

Not talking about an empty project folder, but a project folder containing basic files and configuration.

Maybe one of those?

- skeleton project
- blanko project
- blank project

Comment: Skeleton, blank, boilerplate, template, framework, example, standard, sample, precedent, reference are all ok. Blanko is not.

Comment: Boilerplate is most common. Framework, example, standard, sample, precedent and reference all mean different things.

Answer (score 6):

I think you're talking about a template.  Per Merriam-Webster:

> tem·plate
>
> *computers* : a computer document that has the basic format of something
> (such as a business letter, chart, graph, etc.) and that can be used
> many different times

Comment: "template", in my opinion, has the insinuation that it could be used as-is (in a generic form) or customized at will. i believe that "boilerplate" more accurately represents the idea of something that isn't ready to use, but gives a head-start towards creating a usable product.

Answer (score 5):

*Boilerplate* or *framework* are industry terms for standardized project code; as [CDO defines it](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/boilerplate)

> text that can be copied and used in legal documents or in computer programs, with only very small changes

LDOCE and ODO mark it as an Americanism.

I am less inclined to recommend *framework* as it is used loosely, and can mean different things in different contexts. Broadly, it is a [abstraction of code](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5381/What-Is-A-Framework) which offers predefined code for handling complex operations in a systematic way, but is also used to refer to any development environment or platform.

While *template* would also be acceptable, and perhaps better understood if writing for a general audience— [HTML5Boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/) calls itself "web's most popular front-end template"— I think of a template as a skeleton for an individual page or page component, and a *[snippet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snippet_(programming))* as a small piece of re-usable code that is itself rarely modified. At the project level, a boilerplate would be composed of multiple templates and snippets organized into *[patterns](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns)*.

Certainly, *boilerplate* is a term front-end developers are accustomed to: Mashable has its list of [20 boilerplates and frameworks](http://mashable.com/2013/04/26/css-boilerplates-frameworks/), among which [Skeleton](http://getskeleton.com/) calls itself "a beautiful boilerplate…" and [Goldilocks](http://goldilocksapproach.com/) offers "boilerplate CSS and HTML files based on current best practices"— though I hesitate to point out [Gridless](http://thatcoolguy.github.io/gridless-boilerplate/) being "an optionated HTML5 and CSS3 boilerplate" as I don't care to help popularize "optionated" if I can avoid it.

Comment: +1 because "boilerplate" has a more defined meaning in the software development world than "template" (which could mean nearly anything).
"framework", although sometimes used (with dubious accuracy) to describe this type of thing, usually means something different in the software world (it is a little bit closer to a "code library" than a "boilerplate").

Answer (score 4):

I would use "project template"